# Why does rust create an f32 smaller then f32::MIN_POSITIVE?

Tags: rust, floating-point

This code:

```
        let a = 1.00000003E-27f32;
        let b = 3.19291373E+17f32;
        println!("{:e} < {:e}", a/b, std::f32::MIN_POSITIVE);
```

produces this result:

```
3e-45 < 1.1754944e-38
```

First I expected zero because `MIN_POSITIVE` is the minimum normal positive number. Then I've read about [subnormal numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subnormal_number). So does rust print that result because it is a subnormal number ? But then, why is it not displayed as a subnormal number ?

Comment: "why is it not displayed as a subnormal number" - and how do you expect subnormal numbers to be displayed?

Comment: @wiz21 "So does rust print that result because it is a subnormal number ?" --> Yes.  "But then, why is it not displayed as a subnormal number ?" --> `3e-45` looks like a subnormal to me.

Comment: @Cerberus Somehow I thought that subnormal numbers would be printed with zeros at the beginning of the mantissa.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why does rust create an f32 smaller then f32::MIN_POSITIVE?

Because `MIN_POSITIVE` is a bad name. It is not the minimum positive representable number, it is the minimum positive representable normal number. There are positive representable values less than it, called subnormal numbers.

> So does rust print that result because it is a subnormal number ?

The calculated result of `a/b` is 2.80259692864963414184745916657983226256052388375303154351413656777958216537172120297327637672424316•10<sup>−45</sup>. Rust prints `3e-45` because that is the result of formatting 2.80259692864963414184745916657983226256052388375303154351413656777958216537172120297327637672424316•10<sup>−45</sup> using `:e` for the `f32` type.

> But then, why is it not displayed as a subnormal number ?

There is no special format for subnormal numbers. They are numbers and are formatted like numbers. (The number of digits used may be affected by the coarseness of the subnormal numbers. That is, because the relative spacing of subnormal numbers is smaller, fewer digits may be needed to distinguish a subnormal number from its numbers.)